# Python script to import a PDF/Image to Odoo

Tags: pdf, odoo

I want to upload some .pdf (or .png) files to a certain field in Odoo that is already set as a "Binary" field with a "pdf_viewer" widget by using a Python script so i don't have to upload it manually everytime.

I have tried both: To just use the Odoo function "write" to the field where i want my pdf and then just to enter the local path of the pdf file in my computer.And to use base64.encodebytes for the case of uploading images.

For the first case this is the Odoo 'write' line

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, model_name, 'write', [[new_id], {
    'pdf_field': r"C:\Users\User1\PDFfile.pdf
```

For the Image case:

```
image_base64 = base64.encodebytes(image)
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, model_name, 'write', [[new_id], {
    'pdf_field': image_base64)
```

When i check the Odoo database I obtain a pdf widget but the following message is displayed:

```
"Message: Unexpected server response (500) while retrieving PDF"
```

For the image case, I directly don't see any image

Answer (score 1):

All of file in Odoo must be encoding b64 for Binary field.

Try to use base64.b64encode method .

For PDF

```
with open(path, "rb") as pdf_file:
   pdf_file_encode = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
   models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, model_name, 'write', [[new_id], {
       'pdf_field': pdf_file_encode})
```

For image

```
image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image)
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, model_name, 'write', [[new_id], {
    'pdf_field': image_base64)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/12.0/odoo/fields.py", line 1774, in convert_to_column\n    if value[:1] == b\'P\':  # Fast detection of first 6 bits of \'<\' (0x3C)\nTypeError: \'Binary\' object is not subscriptable\n'>

Comment: With image or pdf ?

Comment: With both cases